# Rails - using is_a? with class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When using `class_name`, how do you check if an instance is not the type of class, but the type of name you've given the class?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :dog1, class_name: 'Dog', foreign_key: 'dog_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_one :dog2, class_name: 'Dog', foreign_key: 'dog_id', dependent: :destroy
end
```

In other words, how do you check if `@dog` is a `dog1` and not a `dog2`?

```
@dog = Dog.find_by(name: 'Gnasher')
if @dog.is_a?(dog1)
  # do some stuff
end
```

Comment: Try `@dog.class.model_name` not sure though

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `@dog == dog1`. Or, at least, `@dog.id == dog1.id`

Comment: I don't think this would work because there are many `dog1`s, each belonging to a different user.

Comment: @Bazley: yeah, in this case, I have no idea what your question is about.

Comment: @Bazley Did you tried my suggestion?

Comment: I've tried it but no success. `@dog.model_name` and `@dog.class.model_name` return the same thing, an ActiveModel::Name object. You can do `@dog.model_name.name` but this just returns `Dog`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check that using `is_a` because both will be instances of Dog.

```
dog1 = @user.dog1
@dog = Dog.find_by(name: 'Gnasher')
if @dog == dog1
  # do some stuff
end
```

api docks: https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3f

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question correctly or not but is_a just check if class is the class of obj, or if class is one of the superclasses of obj or modules included in obj. 
look at this https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F

by adding has_one to a class you are making an association not inheritance and is_a just for checking inheritance